# Get values by latest index of nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, ordereddictionary

How can i get value by the latest key of nested dictionary if i don't know all keys?

For example:

```
dict = { students: { id1: value1, id2: value2, id3: value3} , lecturers: {}}
>>> dict[id2]
value2
```

Also, if I want to change or delete dict[students][id2] by writing only dict[id2]...

Comment: waht do you mean by latest here???

Comment: `"id2"` is not key of `main dict`, It is key of `key1 dict` which is key of `main dict`. You statement `>>> dict[id2]` is wrong

Comment: dict is unordered you cant keep track

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple values of `id2` in separate subdictionaries?

Comment: @Hackaholic: By "latest", I think OP means "deepest"

Comment: 1) `dict` is already a built in function in Python, reusing it to mean something else is confusing. 2) You do know all keys - `d.keys()` will tell you them. 3) You can probably arrange to magically reference `dict[students[id2]]` by writing `dict[id2]` with a lot of subclassing and overloading, but it's confusing and silly - why can't you write `dict[students[id2]]` or put students and lecturers in separate dictionaries?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Try asking the question in a different way. It may be that a nested dictionary is not the correct data type for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in comments, 'dict' is a special word in python, and shouldn't be reused as a variable name, as it can lead to conflicts and strange behaviour.

It's also worth remembering here that dictionaries in python don't (necessarily) retain their order.  [From the docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

What you've done is nested a dictionary, so the first dictionary (key: students) will return the second dictionary (with the various ids, etc.)  It's also worth noting, unless you've assigned students a value elsewhere, you can't use it as a key, it needs to be a string, tuple or number.

So - if you mean 'deepest' then you need to use the structure:

`dictionary_name['top_key']` to access the nested dictionary, and then the second key, giving you something that looks like `dictionary_name['students']['id1']` (note the quotation marks round the key names here!)

If you mean 'latest' as in 'most recently added', then you need to use a different structure, [like OrderedDict.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) I've split this out so you can see how to update the dictionary, which was the latter part of the question!

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dictionary_name = OrderedDict()
dictionary_name.update({"student" : {} })
```